# Object as a checkbox value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects and I map through them.

```
    {alltasks.map((task) => (
    <div key={task.task}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="task" id={task.task} value={task} className="hidden peer check" />
        <label for={task.task} className="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 text-white bg-transparent border-2 border-slate-600 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-emerald-500 hover:border-emerald-700">                           
            <div>
                <img src={task.img} alt="" />
                
                <div className="w-full text-sm mt-2">ID: {task.task}</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
            
    ))}
```

Each object will now have its own checkbox. I set the checbox's value as the object, so I can use it later.

On submit I want to get all checked checbox's values, so I can store them in an array.

```
    <form className="w-full taskForm" onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=task]:checked');
        checkedBoxes.forEach((box) => {
            console.log(box.value)
        })
        stateChanger(false)
    }}>
```

But all I get back is `[object Object]` not the actual object. How can I get back the actual objects?

Comment: You shouldn't mix native JS DOM methods with React. The former will conflict with the latter's way of reconciling the DOM. You should be using state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using React?

Your problem is that you try to assign something that isn't a string to a value on an input field. JavaScript will atomatically try to make the object into a string giving back **[Object.object]**.

You are already on to the solution since you use key and id with values **task.task**.

Set the value to **task.task** as well and see what happens.

If you need to look up the object again after reading the value use something like:

```
allTasks.find(x => x.task = task)
```

to get the object back from the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather set the value of the checkbox to be a unique Id or the `task.task` value, and then after getting your checkboxes, you can loop over each checkbox and find the object with that unique value/id from the `alltasks` array

```
{alltasks.map((task) => (
<div key={task.task}>
    <input type="checkbox" name="task" id={task.task} value={task.task} className="hidden peer check" />

          {/* REST OF CODE HERE */}

        </div>
    </label>
</div>
        
))}
```

And then for the onSubmit function:

```
<form className="w-full taskForm" onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedTasks = []
    const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=task]:checked');
    checkedBoxes.forEach((box) => {
        selectedTasks.push(alltasks.find((task)=> task.task === box.value))
    })
    console.log(selectedTasks)
    stateChanger(false)
}}>
```

And now you have a new array `selectedTasks` containing the objects of the tasks chosen through the checkboxes.